# Passing a variable inside a Set attribute value

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, url-rewriting, submit, setattribute

Can someone please let me know if it is possible to pass a variable inside a "setAttribute" to make an input value appear in an href link?

For example I have :

```
var inputNumber = document.getElementById('inputNumber').value;
var validateBtn = document.getElementsByTagName("a"); //a surrounding n button
var linkValidation = validateBtn[0].href = ("https://checkyournumber.com.action?inputNumber=" + inputNumber );
```

so far so good, if i console.log linkValidation, i do have the full link with the input number at the end as intended.
However when i try to set the href attribute to the a tag in the html using the below :

```
document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].setAttribute("href", "https://checkyournumber.com.action?inputNumber=" + inputNumber );
```

Then the link the user is taken to is : https://checkyournumber.com.action?inputNumber=

I have tried entering inputNumber inside the "" but then of course it is displayed as such in the URL. I have tried with '' instead... no luck.

Would someone know if it is possible at all?

Thank you very much for your support in advance!

Comment: Most probably the problem is that when this code `var inputNumber = document.getElementById('inputNumber').value;` is executed the `#inputNumber` element is empty.

Comment: OK. So assigning the href using this should technically work: 

document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].setAttribute("href", "https://checkyournumber.com.action?inputNumber=" + inputNumber ); ?

Comment: Yes it should ...provide a [mcve] that reproduces your problem

Comment: works like a charm [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ls91wzuj/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Try as follows

```
(function() {


    var inputNumber = document.getElementById('inputNumber').value;
    var validateBtn = document.getElementsByTagName("a"); //a surrounding n button
    var linkValidation = validateBtn[0].href = ("https://checkyournumber.com.action?inputNumber=" + inputNumber );


});
```